# clearInterval not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have so far

```
<div>
    <img src="robot.png" id="robotPic">
</div>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" name="Start" value="Start" id="Start" onclick="moveImage();">
<script type="text/javascript">
var moving = false;
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
var i = 0;

function moveImage() {
    if (!moving) {
        moving = true;
        var robotMoving = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("robotPic").style.paddingLeft = i + "px";
            i = i + 10;
        }, 500);
    } else {
        clearInterval(robotMoving);
    }
}
</script>
```

For whatever reason, the `robotPic` doesn't stop moving when I click the `Start` button again for some reason and I don't understabd

Comment: *robotMoving* is local to the function. When you call *moveImage* a second time, it's a different instance of the function and *robotMoving* variable. Simple fix is to make *robotMoving* global (but there are better ways).

Comment: @Spaceman: Not setting it back to false does not at all explain why the robot never stops moving. It might explain the UNASKED QUESTION of why the robot cannot move more than once.

Comment: @slebetman your correct I think my mind just jumped to conclusions there. apologies I messed up. Robg is correct entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your interval reference `robotMoving` lives only inside that function scope. Which means it's set to undefined every time you run that function (and you're running it multiple times). To fix it, move the variable `robotMoving` outside of that function, and just modify its value from the inside.

Answer (score 3):

Your interval is out of scope.

Perhaps add try this.

Shomz has a good explination in his awnser as to whats happening.

```
var moving = false,
    screenWidth = window.innerWidth,
    i = 0,
    interval;

function moveImage() {
    if (!moving) {
        moving = true;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("robotPic").style.paddingLeft = i + "px";
            i = i + 10;
        }, 500);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accurate but that doesn't fix his problem. The problem is robotMoving is a local variable

Comment: You're answering a question that was not asked. This may be fine as an additional info to an answer but is not an answer in itself.

Comment: Sorry fellas messed up a bit there.